# Show that $a(\gcd (n,k))$ is generated from roots of generating function of $\sum _{h=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=1}^n x^{h n+k} a(\gcd (n,k))\right)$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots, generating-functions, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a(n)$ be the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function:

$$a(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} d \cdot \mu(d) \tag{1}$$

And let the matrix $T$ be:
$$T(n,k)=a(\gcd(n,k)) \tag{2}$$

Compute the ordinary generating functions:

$$q(n)=\sum _{h=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=1}^n x^{h n+k} a(\gcd (n,k))\right) \tag{3}$$

starting:

$$q(1,2,3,...)=\frac{x}{1-x},\frac{x}{x+1},\frac{2 x^2+x}{x^2+x+1},\frac{x}{x+1},\frac{4 x^4+3 x^3+2 x^2+x}{x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1},\frac{x-2 x^2}{x^2-x+1},\frac{6 x^6+5 x^5+4 x^4+3 x^3+2 x^2+x}{x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1},\frac{x}{x+1},\frac{2 x^2+x}{x^2+x+1},\frac{-4 x^4+3 x^3-2 x^2+x}{x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1},...$$

Compute the roots of the denominators of $q(n)$.

**Question:**

> Show that apart from signs, the matrix $T(n,k)=a(\gcd(n,k))$ can be
> generated from powers of those roots.

In Mathematica the essential command, for which I don't know the latex for, is:

```
Total[(x /. Solve[denominator[[n]] == 0, x])^k]
```

where `x /.` removes the `x` symbol.

Mathematica program to demonstrate it is true for the first few terms of the matrix:

```
Clear[s, x, a, t, q]; nn = 7;
a[n_] := Total[Divisors[n]*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]];
Monitor[q = 
   Table[Sum[
     Sum[a[GCD[n, k]]*x^(n*h + k), {k, 1, n}], {h, 0, Infinity}], {n, 
     1, nn}];, n]; denominator = q^-1;
TableForm[Round[Table[Table[a[GCD[n, k]], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]]
TableForm[
 Round[Table[
   Table[Total[(x /. Solve[denominator[[n]] == 0, x])^k], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]]
```

Comparison of outputs:

The original infinite matrix starting:

$$\begin{array}{lllllll}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -4 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -6
\end{array}$$

compared to the infinite matrix starting:

$$\begin{array}{lllllll}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 6
\end{array}$$

where only the signs differ.

Related:

[Show that these ratios have numerators $\frac{1}{2} \vartheta(n) (-\exp (\Lambda (n)))$ and denominators $\exp (\Lambda (n))$ for $x=1$,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4750704/8530)

Comment: I get a different result for $q(1,2,3,...)$, for example the first result for $n=1$ is $\frac{x}{1-x}$ instead of $\frac{x}{x+1}$. The question seems to be related to your [OEIS entry A231425](https://oeis.org/A231425).

Comment: It was a copy paste error. I corrected that now.

Comment: I conjecture that the signs are: (-1)^(PrimeNu[n]).