definition of cyclotomic polynomials
The $n$th cyclotomic polynomial can be expressed via the Mobius function as follows:
$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\substack{1\le d\le n\\d\mid n}}(x^d - 1)^{\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$
In every reference I have encountered, the cyclotomic polynomials are defined in terms of roots of unity. It seems, though, that there are quite a few things one can say about cyclotomic polynomials that have nothing to do with roots of unity.
Is it possible to sidestep this by taking the above as a definition? Can one, say, using the above, show that:

$\Phi_n$ is monic with integer coefficients
the degree of $\Phi_n$ is $\phi(n)$
the above expression is in fact a polynomial
$x^n - 1 = \displaystyle\prod_{\substack{1\le d\le n\\ d\mid n}}\Phi_d(x)$

I'm not asking for proofs of the above statements; I'm merely asking if the display works as a definition.

Isn’t your last bullet point equivalent to your proposed definition using the Möbius inversion formula?

oh, I guess that means I need $1\le d\le n$ in the definition as well. fixed.

A bit unrelated but I would say that there is a better set of polynomials to study, than the cyclotomic polynomials, that coincide with the cyclotomic polynomials at prime numbers. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4774350/8530

Yes, this works as a definition. You do need to prove that $\Phi_n(x)$ is actually a polynomial. Since Möbius inversion makes this identity equivalent to
$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$$
it is a little easier to see what actually needs to be proven by rewriting the definition as the recursion
$$\Phi_n(x) = \frac{x^n - 1}{\prod_{d \mid n, d < n} \Phi_d(x)}.$$
So, what needs to be proven by strong induction on $n$ is that $x^n - 1$ is divisible by the product of all $\Phi_d(x)$ for all proper divisors $d$ of $n$. Since $\Phi_d(x) \mid x^d - 1 \mid x^n - 1$ it is clear that $x^n - 1$ is divisible by each $\Phi_d(x)$ individually. So what needs to be proven is that it is divisible by all of them together. This would follow if you knew that they were relatively prime (over $\mathbb{Q}$), which is true and can be proven without referencing roots of unity, so you can try to proceed by proving that by strong induction.
Once you know that the $\Phi_n(x)$ are actually polynomials (over $\mathbb{Q}$) it follows that they are monic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ since you are dividing two monic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ above (by strong induction). Then writing
$$n = \deg (x^n - 1) = \sum_{d \mid n} \deg \Phi_d(x)$$
and applying Möbius inversion again shows that $\deg \Phi_n(x) = \varphi(n)$.

However, it seems difficult to explain why you would conjecture that this family of polynomials exists without saying something about roots of unity. The roots of $x^n - 1$ over any field $K$ are, by definition, exactly the $n^{th}$ roots of unity in $K$, and the roots of $\Phi_d(x)$ over $K$ are exactly the primitive $d^{th}$ roots of unity in $K$ (assuming the characteristic does not divide $n$). So what this factorization is saying conceptually is that every $n^{th}$ root of unity is a primitive $d^{th}$ root of unity for a unique divisor $d$ of $n$ (namely its multiplicative order).

Of course we may need to pass to an algebraic extension so the roots of unity actually exist. But the point is that this discussion is not specific to $\mathbb{C}$, if that's what you were unsatisfied with. So we can run the above argument over a splitting field of $x^n - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example. The main thing that's nice about $\mathbb{C}$ is that it's very clear there that the group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity is cyclic, and over an arbitrary field we have to prove this.

(For this see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic/)
